# FFmpeg.wasm - retrieve video metadata with node js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, metadata, webassembly

I want to retrieve metadata from a converted video using FFmpeg web assembly package.
I tried to extract a `metadata.txt` file to my current directory but nothing was return from my command

in my `index.js file`:

```js
const { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } = require('@ffmpeg/ffmpeg')

const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true })
await ffmpeg.load()

await ffmpeg.run('-i', "myvideo.avi'", '-f', 'ffmetadata', 'metadata.txt')
```

I got error :

`Output file is empty, nothing was encoded.`

Is this kind of command available on this wasm package? Found nothing relevant on their documentation and I want to avoid the global FFmpeg installation

Comment: Did it create an empty `metadata.txt`? If so, are you sure `myvideo.avi` contains file/stream metadata? (i.e., have you tested the command with regular ffmpeg?)

Answer (score 1):

Wasm doesn't read from the file system. You need to copy files into wasm virtual file system for it to be able to reference files.